# Can I make a Github action to highlight parts for review, like print debug statements?

Tags: github

There are a couple of potential issues which I would like to get highlighted when I make a PR / read a PR on Github:

- print
- logger.debug
- pytest.xfail

Those all have valid cases, but quite often those are only left-overs that should be removed before a PR gets merged.

I know how to check for those things and how to make CI fail when they exist (e.g. with flake8). I know that I can use `# noqa` or similar to add exceptions. But that is not what I'm looking for.

Is there a way to make Github add a warning / add a comment to the PR that those should be investigated, without affecting CI?

Comment: Off-topic, should go for https://webapps.stackexchange.com/ or SO